# Подскажите регулярное выражение для размеров записанных через х

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка
`"Комплектующие на кровать с ламелями 1400х2000"` которая содержит размер **"1400х2000"**. Также может быть и такая строка
`"Шкаф для платья и белья, 1200х600х2210"` она содержит немного другой формат размера **"1200х600х2210"**. Подскажите регулярное выражение для выборки размера из строки. Заранее большое спасибо :)

Comment: А какие варианты вы пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему регулярное выражение должно выглядеть так:

```
\d*\wх\d*\wх*\d*
```

пример на regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hLPoUL/4

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вот так можно

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?:\d)+/', "Шкаф для платья и белья, 1200х600х2210", $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}

Result: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1200 [1] => 600 [2] => 2210 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так (на JS):

```js
const str = "Комплектующие на кровать с ламелями 1400х2000. Шкаф для платья и белья, 1200х600х2210.";

const re = /\d+(?:х\d+)+/gu;

console.log(str.match(re));
```